# How to handle a specific condition and test for it

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have the following code.

```
MAXIMUM_DAYS = 7

def foo(start_date = None, end_date = None):


    if abs((parse(start_date) - parse(end_date)).days) > MAXIMUM_DAYS:
        return ?
```

How do I write the function in such a way that it exits/errors and I can test for that behavior?

I see the AssertRaises method in unittest. Is it as simple as creating a custom exception and raising it in the function, then testing for it in the unit test?

If so, are there standards about how and where to write the exception?

Is there a good example of this somewhere in the documentation or online?

Thanks,

Shawn

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track - using an exception is a common technique for what you have in mind.  `assert` throws an exception, but it is not typically used in production code because `assert` statements can be disable on the command line.  Instead, for your case raising a `ValueError` assertion would be a good choice:

```
MAXIMUM_DAYS = 7

def foo(start_date = None, end_date = None):

    if abs((parse(start_date) - parse(end_date)).days) > MAXIMUM_DAYS:
        raise ValueError(f'Date range exceeds max: {MAXIMUM_DAYS}')
```

Answer (score 1):

Caveat... my assumption is that you are asking how to raise an exception if the value of your calculation is greater than MAXIMUM_DAYS. Based upon that assumption here is my answer.

Start by defining your exception:

```
class GreaterThanMaximumDays(Exception):
  pass
```

Then simply in your code

```
MAXIMUM_DAYS = 7

def foo(start_date = None, end_date = None):
  start_date_value = parse(start_date)
  end_date_value = parse(end_date)
  date_difference = abs(start_date_value - end_date_value)
  if date_difference > MAXIMUM_DAYS:
    raise GreaterThanMaximumDays()

  return date_difference
```

Your guess as to if it is this easy and as easy as using AssertRaises is correct.

Personally, I like defining my own exceptions so this way I can easily test for its existence in my exception handling. I find it makes my code easier to read and understand exactly what I expect to be valid.

> I pulled out the parsed values into their own variables. This simply makes debugging easier if you need to inspect the returned values for any reason at all.

Comment: One improvement would be to extend the `GreaterThanMaximumDays` exception class from `ValueError` instead of `Exception`. @rhurwitz suggests using this in his answer and it is a good suggestion. If you did this then you could generically catch `ValueError` while still being able to distinctly see that the error was `GreaterThanMaximumDays` if needed.